# Вынос элементов Map-коллекции в поле класса

Tags: java, коллекции

имеется код класса-отправщика писем(фрагмент кода ниже):

```
public class MailSender {

    private final static  String USERNAME = "mail-box adres";
    private final static String PASSWORD = "mail-box password";

    Connection connection;

    public MailSender(Connection connect) {
        connection=connect;
    }

    public  void send(List<Message> messageList) throws MessagingException {
        if (messageList==null) throw new NullPointerException("Message error");

        MailRepository dataModificator=new MailRepository(connection);

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
        props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "smtp.gmail.com");

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(USERNAME, PASSWORD);
                    }
                });
```

Хочу вынести коллекцию props за пределы метода(сделать полем класса),сделав ее и ее значения константными.С данным типом коллекций работал мало,подскажите пожалуйста как это можно сделать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я в таких случаях использую такой хак:

```
public class MyClass {

    private static final Properties props = new Properties(){{
        put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
        put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "smtp.gmail.com");
    }};

}
```

А если хотите неизменяемые значения внутри коллекции, то нужно использовать `Immutable` коллекции из `Google Guava`, там и без хаков можно обойтись, используя `builder`:

```
private static final ImmutableMap<String, String> props = ImmutableMap.<String, String>builder()
        .put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true")
        .put("mail.smtp.auth", "true")
        .put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com")
        .put("mail.smtp.port", "587")
        .put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "smtp.gmail.com")
        .build();
```

Comment: ваш хак сработал)но еще есть небольшой вопрос, а вот синтаксически, как мне отдельно прописать в виде констант параметры подключения(пары ключ-значение)?

Comment: Что значит отдельно в виде констант? Вынести их в константные поля типа `String`? Или прямо парами чтобы?

Comment: вот к примеру сделать пару "mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true" константой

Comment: Ну можно создать массив из двух элементов `String[] param1 = new String[]{"mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true"};`
Можно создать `org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.Pair`, например: `Pair<String, String> param1 = Pair.of("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");`
По всякому можно, что вам больше по душе.

Comment: Примерно понял. Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать `ImmutableMap` из [Google Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html).
Она действительно хорошо защищена от изменения, как самого объекта map так и содержания мапы.